# CLI terraform apply on update generates error, x509: <cluster_ip> certificate is not standards compliant

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-cli

I have a pretty simple terraform configuration that simply creates a cluster in google cloud.

The first "terraform apply" creates the cluster as expected, any subsequent changes to the configuration get greeted with:

x509: <cluster_ip> certificate is not standards compliant

E.g.
Error: Get "https://<cluster_ip>/api/v1/namespaces/hub": x509: “<cluster_ip>” certificate is not standards compliant

It looks like on an update, terraform will query the cluster resources to compare states and at that point the error occurs.

I upgraded versions for terraform, now using 1.5.0 and kubernetes, now using 1.25.9 in client, 1.25.8 on cluster.

I also created the cluster in different regions, also different OS (MacOS, Linux) and machines.

I also tried to get the certificate from the cluster and add it to my machine certificates as trusted ones, basically I followed this: https://jhooq.com/x509-certificate-signed/ but no luck.

Comment: Edit your post and provide details. Show the command, relevant configuration files (HCL), error message along with what generated the error message, etc.

Comment: Are you running Terraform on macOS? I wonder if you have encountered the behavior change described in this Go issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51991 (Terraform and the providers you are using are written in Go, so are possibly depending on the library that issue is talking about.)

Comment: Hi @MartinAtkins, it could be related, the problem occurs in several OS, Mac and Linux, using the simplest terraform that creates a cluster. The problem also looks like it might be intermittent, it  doesn't happen all the time. Sometimes it seems to work for a while although of lately it seems to happen a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the underlying problem is, but here is a workaround,

https://jhooq.com/x509-certificate-signed/

to summarize, you get the problematic certificate either saving it with your browser or with the openssl command in a crt format

```
openssl s_client -connect registry.terraform.io:443 2>/dev/null </dev/null |\
sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'
```

load and add the certificate to your OS certificate storage and trust it.